# Angular2 ngSwitch not working

Tags: angular, ng-switch, angularjs-ng-switch

I have an ngSwitch for a model attribute bound to a drop-down.  It wasn't working, so I tried to simply hard-code the value.  Still doesn't work, it displays *both* divs.  What am I doing wrong?  Apologies in advance if it's something obvious, I'm new to Angular2.

**My html template:**

```
      <!-- display closed date if status is closed, otherwise display active date -->
      <div ngSwitch="ACTV">
          <div class="form-group row" ngSwitchWhen="CLSD">
            <label for="closeDt" class="col-md-4 form-control-label text-md-right">
                                        Close Date
                                        <span class="help-block">Required field</span>
                                    </label>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
              <datetime [timepicker]="false" [(ngModel)]="date2" id="close-date" name="close-date"></datetime>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group row" ngSwitchWhen="ACTV">
            <label for="issueDt" class="col-md-4 form-control-label text-md-right">
                                        Active Date
                                        <span class="help-block">Required field</span>
                                    </label>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
              <datetime [timepicker]="false" [(ngModel)]="date2" id="active-date" name="active-date"></datetime>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
```

**Result on the npm server:**

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What version of angular2 are you using? In the final (release) version the syntax that works for me is:

```
<div [ngSwitch]="someVariable">
  <div *ngSwitchCase="value1">...</div>
  <div *ngSwitchCase="value2">...</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 23):

***In case DEMO required : https://plnkr.co/edit/SCZC5Cx9gnQbg1AkkspX?p=preview***

Change,

**1)**

```
ngSwitch="ACTV"        TO     [ngSwitch]="'ACTV'"
```

**2)**

```
ngSwitchWhen="CLSD"    TO     *ngSwitchCase="'CLSD'"
```

**3)**

```
ngSwitchWhen="ACTV"    To     *ngSwitchCase="'ACTV'"
```

Comment: 2) made my day - unexpected behavior.

Comment: This answer is helpful (it helped me!), but I suspect #1 is incorrect (not what the OP or others will want to do). If the switch expression is a string literal ('ACTV'), then the switch will always match the 2nd case. The first case will never show. I suspect that ACTV is a variable that can have values 'ACTV' or 'CLSD'. IOW, remove the single quotes from #1. ...  It is confusing that the variable has the same name as one its possible values. Maybe the variable should have a different name.

Comment: Why is it that `[ngSwitch]` works but `*ngSwitch` does not? I thought, the `*` was just syntactic sugar for structural directives? 

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax for using isn't correct. It should be `[ngSwitch]="switch_expression"` and then the cases should look like this `<some-element *ngSwitchCase="match_expression_1">`

See [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgSwitch-directive.html) for how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

you have to test on object attributs

```
switch_expression { 
     match_expression_1: value1, 
     match_expression_2: value2, 
     match_expression_3: value3,  
}
```

and then :

```
<div [ngSwitch]="switch_expression">
   <div  *ngSwitchCase="match_expression_1">...</div>
   <div  *ngSwitchCase="match_expression_2">...</div>
</div>
```

for more informations : 
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgSwitch-directive.html

Answer (score 0):

If the variable you are switching on gets updated via subscription, try adding async pipe:

```
<div [ngSwitch]="someVariable" | async>
```

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/AsyncPipe-pipe.html